# Is 94 cubic feet/hour of natural gas a heavy load?

Tags: natural-gas

Is natural gas fuel consumption of 94 cubic ft/hr a high or low consumption? (How does it compare to a stove, oven or clothes dryer?)

I am trying to figure out if I can run a small standby generator off my existing NG hardware. I have an ANSI meter #250.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cubic foot of gas contains approximately 1,000 BTUs of heat, so 94 cubic feet of gas per hour = 94,000 BTUs per hour. That's about as much as a large gas furnace might draw, three times a typical gas clothes dryer, and twice a typical gas range with everything lit. One burner might be 9,000 BTUs.

If you need to ask the internet for help with this type of calculation, you really should not be performing natural gas work yourself. Don't blow yourself up. If you live in NYC, as your name suggests, doing so is highly illegal and puts other people in danger as well.

Comment: I will have a licensed plumber do the work.  I would lke to have some idea what makes sense to help me evaluate what the various plumbers recommend I do.  Too often, even licensed practioners provide very diverse information and recommendations.

Comment: That's quite true!